# looping over a list of dictionaries, creating a new list of dictionary

Tags: python

Need some help with my code, basically I have a list containing dictionary:

example

```
my_list = [
{'trans' : 50,'portfolio' : ABC},
{'trans' : 30,'portfolio' : XYZ},
{'trans' : 20, 'portfolio : ABC},
{'trans' : -40, 'portfolio : XYZ}
]
```

I want to loop through this list of dicts, creating a new list of dict where the key is the 'portfolio' and value is a dict that is update based on condition. For example, the new list would look like this:

```
new_list = [
{ABC : [BUY : 70, SELL : 0]},
{XYZ : [BUY : 30 , SELL : -40]}
]
```

***Notice that ABC value ->  BUY[buy] is a sum of my 'tran' > 0 and if no sell set to 0, XYZ -> BUY is 30 is the sum is just itself, and SELL is now populated

here is what I got so far, which I know is wrong but lost no how to rewrite it

```
from collections import defaultdict

buy = 0
sell = 0
 new_dict = defaultdict(lamba: {'BUY' :0,'SELL' : 0})
     for row in my_list:
         if row['tran'] > 0:
           buy += row['tran']
           update = {'BUY': buy}
         else:
           sell += row['tran']
           update = {'SELL' : sell}
         new_dict[row['portfolio']] = update
```

As you can see I just keep incrementing buy/sell regardless of the 'portfolio' but I want them to only increment for a giving 'portfolio' (key) in my new dict based on the if/else logic on the 'tran'. My results from the logic above is below, which is incorrect

```
new_list = [
    {ABC : {BUY : 100, SELL : 0}},
    {XYZ : {BUY : 100, SELL : -40}}
    ]
```

Comment: The code samples you gave are littered with typos. They aren't even syntactically legal. Please fix the basics before asking for help with the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very confused about python data structures, you can't have keys in lists, you don't need a list of dictionaries with only one key. So assuming what you really want is a dictionary where keys are the portfolio, and value is a dictionary of the sum of `buy` and `sell` as separate values:

```
>>> results = {}
>>> for t in my_list:
...     trans = 'BUY' if t['trans'] > 0 else 'SELL'
...     a = results.setdefault(t['portfolio'], {'BUY':0, 'SELL':0})
...     a[trans] += t['trans']
>>> results
{'ABC': {'BUY': 0, 'SELL': 0}, 'XYZ': {'BUY': 0, 'SELL': 0}}
```